# What is the difference between grantingTicketExpirationPolicy and serviceTicketExpirationPolicy in acegi security

Tags: spring, spring-security

What is the difference between grantingTicketExpirationPolicy and serviceTicketExpirationPolicy in acegi security

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is still actual, but I came over this differences when I configured our [CAS server](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Ticket+Expiration+Policy).

**grantingTicketExpirationPolicy** is the policy for the ticketgranting ticket, that is used in the CAS case for genereating the real service tickets

**serviceTicketExpirationPolicy** is the policy for the real service ticket, so for the actual authentication